# Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm facing this error...

I'm trying to use storybook for the first time and when trying to document a component this error appears, the funny thing is that my react application is working normally.

This component StyledLink.js is inside the component called Menu, and Menu is inside NavBar that I am importing directly into the App file

```
// File StyledLink.js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: clamp(3rem, 4vw, 6vw);
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;

  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;

  &:hover {
    transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
    color: orangered;
  }
`;

export default StyledLink;
```

```
// file StyledLink.stories.js
import StyledLink from './StyledLink';

export default {
  title: 'Layouts/NavBar/Menu/StyledComponents/StyledLink',
  component: StyledLink,
};

export const Default = {};
```

```
\\ App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { Home, Page404 } from './Views';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavBar } from './Layouts';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/page-not-found" element={<Page404 />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I saw some answers that could be the lack of BrowserRouter but as you can see I'm wrapping the NavBar component with it

Answer (score 1):

1. Create router-decarator component such as:

```js
    import { ReactNode } from 'react';
    import { FC } from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


    export interface RouterDecoratorProps {
        children: ReactNode;
    }
    const RouterDecorator: FC<RouterDecoratorProps> = ({ children }) => {
    return <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>;
    };

    export default RouterDecorator;
```

2. Add RouterDecorator for global preview.tsx or for your local StyledLink Component such as:

/*preview.tsx*/

```js
import React from "react";
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import RouterDecorator from './router-decorator/router-decorator';

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <RouterDecorator>
        <Story/>
      </RouterDecorator>
    )
    ],
};

export default preview;
```

/*StyledLink*/

```js
  import StyledLink from './StyledLink';
  import RouterDecorator from './router-decorator/router-decorator';
  const meta = {
    title: 'Layouts/NavBar/Menu/StyledComponents/StyledLink',
    component: StyledLink ,
    tags: ['autodocs'],
    args: {
      to: '/'
    }
    decorators: [
(Story) => (
  <RouterDecorator>
    <Story/>
  </RouterDecorator>
)
],
  } satisfies Meta<typeof StyledLink >;

  export default meta;
  type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;
```